# How to integrate JSS to WordPress

Tags: themes, css

WordPress is all about PHP and JSS is... Js. And I want to use JSS but I got trouble in interacting between generated HTML by PHP and CSS from JSS. Like in the official example (https://codesandbox.io/s/z21lpmvv33), JSS generate a version of CSS classes. This means I cannot set fixed classes in WordPress. What should I do?

Comment: I can't think of any reason why you'd want to use this with WordPress. It seems pretty clearly designed for use with React applications and the like.

Comment: Because I don't know how to use React. Moreover, I wanna use vanilla Js on client side. I was looking for a way to convert JSS to CSS via gulp without changing class name so I can use it on PHP files. Do you think it possible?

Comment: But why on earth do you need to use JSS?

Comment: It doesn't have to be JSS, anything that meets my requirement will do. In the past, I used SASS. But with new big upgrade recently, it's no longer meets my requirement anymore so I have to kiss goodbye it.

Comment: And what's your requirement?

Comment: Well, Mikhail had solved my problem. But I don't mind for other suggection so. My requirement is a processor that can export css from Js with no class names changed so I can use it in WordPress theme. The reason I need Js because I want to separate logic task away css rule. (SASS is no longer work for me since the `@import` is decided to be removed in the future)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSS is designed for dynamically generated HTML rendered by JS. It's purpose is to generate unique identifiers for class names to prevent collisions in naming.

If you want to have static CSS generated it's easier to look at LESS\SASS\SCSS and build them with gulp, or with Less straight(http://lesscss.org/usage/).

**Here's heavily modified example which does what you might want**.
https://codesandbox.io/s/core-jss-playground-84yve

All is done using `jss-plugin-global`

Compare it to initial code in how CSS rules are defined with `@global` to make them rendered without enhancing class names with dynamic parts.

Also look at https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-global docs and nested plugin docs https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-global as it's useful.

And probably you'll find it useful to use JSS-CLI https://cssinjs.org/cli/
So with JSS CLI you'll be able to complile JSS into static CSS and serve it via `wp_enqueue_style()` as normal css file.

Or you can build your JS with JSS file from ES6 syntax with webpack+babel and then  use `wp_enqueue_script()` and your built JS will compile inner JSS and inject into page just like in example.